# Image wont apply opacity when writing code

Tags: html, wordpress, image, web

I have this minor issue where I want to insert a picture on my website. I manage to insert the picture but the problem comes when I want to insert an opacity into the code. I want the picture to become some kind of transparent when you hoover over it.

```
 <a href="http://www.byggprojektoren.se" style="opacity: 1;">  <img
 src="Image.jpg"> </a>
```

As it is right now it is not transparent when hoovering over with a mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it a :hover selector with css like this:

```
img:hover {
    opacity:0,4;
}
```

Edit:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
  img:hover {
    opacity:0,4;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.byggprojektoren.se"> 
<img src="http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/HomepagePic.jpg"> 
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I dont know how to insert that into the code I have above, could you assist me with that?

Comment: In my first post I have rewritten the code. Is it the correct way to do so? I have tried the code on my website, but it still wont work.

Comment: I think you should include the style tag in the head tag of your HTML code.

Comment: I am using a wordpress theme so I dont know if It is so smart doing anything in the header.php if the theme needs an update later on. Isnt there any other option to do it inside of the <a></a>? Thanks.

Comment: Not in the header.php. Your html file has something like this: <html><head></head><body></body></html>, right? And you can add the style tag in the head tag.

Comment: No it does not have anything like that. I am using a plugin which is called SiteOrigin Page builder. I have an URL which shows exactly what it is I am trying to accomplish:  http://www.sydarkkonstruera.se/category/konstruktion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61702/discussion-between-flopet17-and-rinorm).

Answer (score 0):

Use css instead of inline styles. You can also use css for the hover style, like this:

```css
img {
  opacity: 1;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="picture.jpg" />
```

Comment: Hi, how can I implement that into the current code I have? Thank you.